# VBA Created pivot table not visible - No errors

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a function which takes several columns of data from sheet 1 and creates a new sheet "Pivottable" with a pivot table with sheet 1's data. However, when the sheet is created there is no visible pivot table.

I have checked for any misspelling, and have viewed other similar programs with nearly identical code. I believe the issue lies with the range function used, but I cannot say for certain, as there are no error messages to locate any bugs. Any help is appreciated!

```
Sub Pvttble()

Dim pvtData As Worksheet
Dim pvtSheet As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
Dim pvtRange As Range

'Creates new sheet to replace old sheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set pvtSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set pvtData = Worksheets("Sheet1")

'Range function for data from sheet1
Set pvtRange = pvtData.Range(Application.Union(Range("B3:C1000"), Range("E3:F1000"), Range("H3:I1000"), Range("K3:L1000"), Range("N3:O1000"), Range("Q3:R1000")))


Set pvtCache = PivotTable.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pvtRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PivotTable.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="ExpensePivotTable")


Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=pvtSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="ExpensePivotTable")

'Formatting pvtTable
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivotTable").PivotFields("Catagory")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 1
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivotTable").PivotFields("Date")
.Orientation = xlColumnField
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("ExpensePivotTable").PivotFields("Cost")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` <-- This is why you don't see any errors.

Comment: Remove the first instance of  `. _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PivotTable.Cells(2, 2), _`

Answer (score 0):

A good tip for troubleshooting is using F8 to step-through the code to determine if each line works as intended.

I think the issue is here:

EDITED:

Your activesheet is the PivotTable sheet and you haven't set pvtRange within the union in terms of a sheet yet. So, I think the code below is pulling from the activesheet, which would be blank.

```
'Range function for data from sheet1
Set pvtRange = pvtData.Range(Application.Union(Range("B3:C1000"), Range("E3:F1000"), Range("H3:I1000"), Range("K3:L1000"), Range("N3:O1000"), Range("Q3:R1000")))`
```

Try changing the ranges after the union to sheets(1).range("...")

Comment: It should be `pvtData.Range("...")` but a valid point. Once that's fixed, the linked dupe will fix the next issue.

Comment: Agreed.  It is defined, but not within the union

Comment: Another option here would be `With pvtData`, `Set pvtRange = Union(.Range("B3:C1000"), .Range("E3:F1000"), ...)`, `End With`.

Comment: With/End With gets around the activesheet issue for sure.